# Java: Rectangle2D and negative dimensions

Tags: java, graphics

I have a script in which the user clicks once to begin a `Rectangle2D`. When he moves the mouse, the rectangle is updated with the new coordinates. He clicks again to end it. It's then stored in an `ArrayList`, and all these items are painted. This all works fine; it's not the problem.

However, if the second click is less than the first (i.e. `getWidth()` is negative), the rectangle doesn't show up (as stated in [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)). My script to fix this doesn't work. It's supposed to detect negative values, and then 1) decrement the position value and 2) make the negatives positive. Instead, it just moves the entire rectangle up or left (depending on which axis is negative) and keeps it at 1px.

What's wrong?

```
private void resizeRectangle(final MouseEvent e) {
    double x = rectangle.getX(), y = rectangle.getY(), w = e.getX() - x, h = e.getY() - y;
    if (w < 0) {
        x = e.getX();
        w = -w;
    }
    if (h < 0) {
        y = e.getY();
        h = -h;
    }
    rectangle.setRect(x, y, w, h);
}
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: This is closer, but still doesn't quite work:

```
double x = rectangle.getX();
double y = rectangle.getY();
double w = e.getX() - x;
double h = e.getY() - y;

if (w < 0) {
    x = e.getX();
    w = originalClickPoint.getX() - e.getX();
}
if (h < 0) {
    y = e.getY();
    h = originalClickPoint.getY() - e.getY();
}
rectangle.setRect(x, y, w, h);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). The source code for the `DrawOnComponent` example shows how I did this.

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get a `NullPointerException` at `DrawOnComponent$DrawingArea$MyMouseListener.mouseReleased` (line 161)...

Comment: I see that there is a little bug if you just click the mouse without actually dragging the mouse to paint a rectangle. This is because the `endPoint` variable hasn't been initialized. Try it again and try dragging the mouse while it is pressed.

Comment: `DrawOnComponent` source code has been updated to fix the bug.

Comment: Thanks for your code and your help - this does make sense. However, I feel that Howard's answer was slightly more direct to my problem; hence, I have accepted his answer – please understand that I am nevertheless grateful for your reply! WC

Comment: @WChargin, I gave you working code (assumning you acutally dragged the mouse to paint a rectangle) 3 hours after you posted your question. The code I gave you is exactly the same as Howard's code (which he posted 10 hours after the code I gave you). I even fixed my little bug and reposted the code 3 hours before Howard updated his answer. I won't make that mistake again.

Comment: Oh dear - I am truly sorry. I guess I just happened to see Howard's post before yours. I do very much appreciate the effort you put in, and, as such, realize that, yes, you do deserve the accepted answer. I hope I have not offended you too badly. WC

Answer (score 3):

Once you assign the new rectangle you also shift the origin (i.e.where the mouse button was pressed down initially) to the current point. You'll have to save this point in a separate field (not in the rectangle itself).

```
x = Math.min(e.getX(), originalClickPoint.getX());
w = Math.abs(originalClickPoint.getX() - e.getX());

y = Math.min(e.getY(), originalClickPoint.getY());
h = Math.abs(originalClickPoint.getY() - e.getY());
```

Another way is to not correct the negative widths/heights of the rectangle but create a new (corrected) one when you draw it.

Comment: Thanks; you've definitely put me on the right track. Can you tell what's wrong here? (Updated question)

Comment: @WChargin See my edit. Note that the if statements are now implicitely contained in the `min` and `abs` methods.